# how to exclude the SENTINEL value from the output in c++?

Tags: c++

how do you exclude the SENTINEL value from the output in c++?
For a school project.
The SENTINEL value is skewing the output and adding it to the calculations. My professor was vague on how to exclude the SENTINEL from my calculations, but I am still confused as to how to exclude it. 
My output for the largest value keeps equaling 99999 which is the SENTINEL value.
It is also adding the SENTINEL value to all the calculations.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>

using namespace std;
int SENTINEL = 99999;
int main()
{
    int min = INT_MAX, max = INT_MIN, num = 0, counter = 0, pos = 0, neg = 0, sum = 0, num2 = 0, tot = 0;
    int even = 0;
    int odd = 0;
    double total = 0;
    while (num != SENTINEL) 
    {
        cout << "Enter in a number" << endl;
        cout << "Enter 99999 to exit" << endl;
        cin >> num;
        if (num > max)
            max = num;
        if (num < min)
            min = num;
        if ((num % 2) != 0)
        {
            odd++;
        }
        else if (num % 2 == 0)
        {
            even++;
        }
        if (num < 99999) {
            neg++;
        }
        if (num < 99) {
            num2++;
        }
        total += num;
        tot += num;
        counter++;
    }
    total = total / counter;
    cout << "The smallest Number of the list is: " << min << endl;
    cout << "The largest Number of the list is: " << max << endl;
    cout << "The sum of all the numbers is: " << tot << endl;
    cout << "The average of all numbers is: " << total << endl;
    cout << "There are " << neg << " numbers" << endl;
    cout << "There are " << even << " even numbers" << endl;
    cout << "There are " << odd << " odd numbers" << endl;
    cout << "There are " << num2 << " numbers smaller than 99" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (num != SENTINEL) { ... }`  You're looping until num becomes a specific value, but you're reading that value and then using it before checking it ...

Answer (score 0):

There are some changes you will have to make:

1. Read the number at least once before the while loop to ensure that the `while`
   is not executed if number is 99999.
2. Move the reading of the number to the end of the while loop so that it can be checked right at the beginning before any further
   processing.
3. Have a check to see if any numbers have to been entered to avoid dividing by zero in the statement `total = total / counter;`
4. The various statements must be output using `cout` only if there are any numbers in the list. Otherwise, it does not make much sense.

After the above changes, the code will look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>

using namespace std;
int SENTINEL = 99999;
int main()
{
    int min = INT_MAX, max = INT_MIN, num = 0, counter = 0, pos = 0, neg = 0, sum = 0, num2 = 0, tot = 0;
    int even = 0;
    int odd = 0;
    double total = 0;
    cout << "Enter in a number" << endl;
    cout << "Enter 99999 to exit" << endl;
    cin >> num;
    while (num != SENTINEL) 
    {            
        if (num > max)
            max = num;
        if (num < min)
            min = num;
        if ((num % 2) != 0)
        {
            odd++;
        }
        else if (num % 2 == 0)
        {
            even++;
        }
        if (num < 99999) {
            neg++;
        }
        if (num < 99) {
            num2++;
        }
        total += num;
        tot += num;
        counter++;
        cout << "Enter in a number" << endl;
        cout << "Enter 99999 to exit" << endl;
        cin >> num;
    }
    if(counter != 0)
    {
        total = total / counter;
        cout << "The smallest Number of the list is: " << min << endl;
        cout << "The largest Number of the list is: " << max << endl;
        cout << "The sum of all the numbers is: " << tot << endl;
        cout << "The average of all numbers is: " << total << endl;
        cout << "There are " << neg << " numbers" << endl;
        cout << "There are " << even << " even numbers" << endl;
        cout << "There are " << odd << " odd numbers" << endl;
        cout << "There are " << num2 << " numbers smaller than 99" << endl;
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "No numbers were entered" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sample Output:

```
./a.exe
Enter in a number
Enter 99999 to exit
99999
No numbers were entered

./a.exe
Enter in a number
Enter 99999 to exit
34
Enter in a number
Enter 99999 to exit
23
Enter in a number
Enter 99999 to exit
12
Enter in a number
Enter 99999 to exit
99999
The smallest Number of the list is: 12
The largest Number of the list is: 34
The sum of all the numbers is: 69
The average of all numbers is: 23
There are 3 numbers
There are 2 even numbers
There are 1 odd numbers
There are 3 numbers smaller than 99
```